# How to resize the draggers of the SplitLayoutPanel in GWT UIBinder template

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I want to make the draggers of the `SplitLayoutPanel` smaller. Can I do that with CSS styling? I tried padding and border, but both have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the splitter size in CSS because the splitter is part of the layout structure, which internally keeps track of the size (for the same reason you need to hardcode sizes on other Layout panels). But you can set the splitter size via the constructor `SplitLayoutPanel(int splitterSize)`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Can I set the constructor parameter in an UIBinder ui.xml file? I tried:

<g:SplitLayoutPanel width='100%' height='100%' splitterSize='1'>

But that gives the error: 
  Class SplitLayoutPanel has no appropriate setSplitterSize() method Element <g:SplitLayoutPanel height='100%' splitterSize='1' width='100%'>

Comment: Yes, but not in the ui.xml in this case. In this case in your java code set `@UiField(provided=true) SplitLayoutPanel mySplitLayoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel(1);` and in the ui.xml add to the SplitLayoutPanel `ui:field=`mySplitLayoutPanel"`. For more information see: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget (ps. it's good practice here on stackoverflow to mark answers that you think are correct as answered)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the size (in pixels) as an attribute on the dock edge element. For example, the following sets a western edge with a width of 150px.

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel>
   <g:west size="150">
     <!--your west edge elements -->
   </g:west>
   <g:center>
     <!--your center elements -->
   </g:west>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```